# How do I connect to the GMAIL API without the oAuth authentication? using js or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth, imap, gmail-api

I am trying to use GMAIL API to access my emails in my inbox because I want to list my emails on my website. But every time someone visits the page,they asked to login/thru google auth. I want the user to see it without google's OAuth authentication so they they will see it immediately. I have also tried PHP IMAP on gmail, but it loads a bit longer to load the email.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to work reliably, you pretty much need to use OAuth.  You'll have to store your OAuth credentials to reuse them.

Comment: @Max, thanks but this email i use is intended for the users the view the emails (without authentication)

Comment: OAuth doesn't prevent that.  After you log in the first time, you should store the various tokens somewhere so they can be reused.  Those tokens should continue to work indefinitely, providing you do the renewals properly.  OAuth does not require you to log in every time.

Comment: Try to check the [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) if it is applicable in your use case. Service account is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. Typically, an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.

Comment: Service accounts only work in gsuite.

Comment: This is a FULL implementation of standard PHP IMAP functions like (imap_open, imap_getmailboxes, imap_*, etc...) https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902